# How to load images into database and then retrieve them onto web page?

Tags: database, image

WHat kind of different databases I can use to store images? And how to display these images onto web page?

Comment: Generally, storing images in a database is discouraged; see [this ancient SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid storing image in database. 
You should store the image in your file system and its url in database

The answer to your question can be found at following links.

Storing image in db

http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=store_images_mysql_php.php

Retrieving image

http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=retreive_images_mysql_php.php

Contact if you have any doubt.